# Prometheus Alertmanager using moving average

Tags: monitoring

Is it possible to create a rule on Prometheus Alertmanager using moving average method? Example:
 In the last 30 minutes the quantity of access on login page is 1.000/minutes but if now it is 15% higher or lower it is time to throw an alert.